# Trigger Cloud Function based on Firestore changes

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to trigger my Cloud function whenever a document is changed(created, modified, removed) for a particular club. My cloud function should capture what data is altered and further publish it to pub/sub.

All this in python.

I tried like this :

`query = db.collection('cities')
 query_watch = col_query.on_snapshot(callback)`

cities -> Firestore collection.

This is my callback function -

```
def callback(col_snapshot, changes, read_time):
print('callback.')
```

This query_watch is of type Watch object. How can I extract details from it like what is the delta.?

followed this doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
# Create a callback on_snapshot function to capture changes
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        # Here you retrieve the data
        print(u'Received document snapshot: {}'.format(doc.id))

doc_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

# Watch the document
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

In your `def callback(col_snapshot, changes, read_time)` you need to process the data received as you like.

print() will run twice because:

> An initial call using the callback you provide creates a document
>   snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document.
>   Then, each time the contents change, another call updates the document
>   snapshot.

Comment: Noted. but for the print is executed twice. 1st time with all the doc.id originally present and 2nd time with new doc.id added.

My question here is why its called twice? and how can we access "changes"

Comment: That is it's behavior, the first time it gives the current contents snapshot and will be triggered only for further changes. Read : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots